# I want to add a key directory directly under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT with batch command (as like a subfolder)

Tags: regedit

I want to add a key folder (..NewKey) directly under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT with batch command (as like a subfolder, on the left side), and then add several keys into this key folder. If i try to do it manualy, and right click HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT i can do this with add key (see picture1) If i try it with reg add command like below, the key is generated directly in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (see picture2) What am i doing wrong?

reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" /v ..NewKey /t REG_SZ /d Server

[image: picture1]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the new key name as part of the `KeyName` parameter, then speecify `/ve`. This creates the key with an empty `(Default)` value. Optionally, add the `/t` and `/d` parameters with approproate values to create the key with a non-empty `(Default)` value.

```
reg add "hkcr\...NewKey" /ve
```

or

```
reg add "hkcr\...NewKey" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "Server"
```

> REG ADD KeyName [/v ValueName | /ve] [/t Type] [/s Separator] [/d
> Data] [/f]
> [/reg:32 | /reg:64]
>
> KeyName  [\Machine]FullKey
> Machine  Name of remote machine - omitting defaults to the
> current machine. Only HKLM and HKU are available on remote
> machines.
> FullKey  ROOTKEY\SubKey
> ROOTKEY  [ HKLM | HKCU | HKCR | HKU | HKCC ]
> SubKey   The full name of a registry key under the selected ROOTKEY.
>
> /v       The value name, under the selected Key, to add.
>
> /ve      adds an empty value name (Default) for the key.
>
> /t       RegKey data types
> [ REG_SZ    | REG_MULTI_SZ | REG_EXPAND_SZ |
> REG_DWORD | REG_QWORD    | REG_BINARY    | REG_NONE ]
> If omitted, REG_SZ is assumed.
>
> /s       Specify one character that you use as the separator in your
> data
> string for REG_MULTI_SZ. If omitted, use "\0" as the separator.
>
> /d       The data to assign to the registry ValueName being added.
>
> /f       Force overwriting the existing registry entry without
> prompt.